# android : moving Image one point to another point

Tags: android, animation

```
Android moving Image one point (0,0) to another point (30,400). using animation or normal

looping condition.
```

Please Tell me some Idea...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: **you need this**
[http://www.twintechs.com/blog/?p=35](http://www.twintechs.com/blog/?p=35)

Comment: Hey this is using multiple image. but i want to use only one image to move one point to another point.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using Translate Animation in android.

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(220, 80, 300, 80); //(float From X,To X, From Y, To Y)
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.setFillAfter(false);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener());
```

Below is the class implementing AnimationListener Interface.

```
 private class MyAnimationListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

    }
```

Atlast set the animation to your view by,

```
view.setAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use **Translate Animation**

here some link for translate animation..

[Method & Class For Translate Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)

[Sample Code for Translate Animation](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LayoutAnimation2.html)

Answer (score 1):

By using Translate animation you can do this.
where inside Translate animation X coordinate is original position minus destination same is for Y coordinate for Example

```
   public TranslateAnimation(x1,X,y1,Y);
   where X=0-30, Y=0-400;
```

Or you can directly use XML for translate animation.place this XML inside /res/anim/translate.translate XML file is as follows-

```
    <set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
      <translate android:fromXDelta="-30" android:fromYDelta="-400"
      android:duration="700" />
     </set>
```

Now in your activity

```
           Animation anim1 =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.translate); 
           yourImage.startAnimation(anim1);
```